# absl/numeric/int128_have_intrinsic.inc' file not found in react native firebase ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

I am getting this error .unable to build .I have tried pod deintegrate  and again pod install but issue. still not fix.

Pods/Headers/Public/abseil/absl/numeric/int128.h:726:10: fatal error: 'absl/numeric/int128_have_intrinsic.inc' file not found

here is my pod version

# Required by RNFirebase

```
  pod 'Firebase/Core', '~> 6.13.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth', '~> 6.13.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Database', '~> 6.13.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Functions', '~> 6.13.0'
  pod 'Firebase/DynamicLinks', '~> 6.13.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore', '~> 6.13.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging', '~> 6.13.0'
  pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig', '~> 6.13.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Storage', '~> 6.13.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Performance', '~> 6.13.0'
  pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.10.2'
  pod 'Crashlytics', '~> 3.14.0'
```

and

```
 "react-native-firebase": "^5.6.0",
  "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.8",
```

let me whats the why its coming

Answer (score 0):

Update to a newer version of CocoaPods. See https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/4355